# How to run command until it succeeds?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I still use Windows batch-files for basic tasks. One of these is to check my internet connection (pg.bat) which does only do a `ping www.google.com`

Most of the time, I need to run it a few times until it succeeds (host could not be found error). At first I thought a `ping -t` would work, but it does not. When the host is not found, it stops right away.

How can I run pg.bat until the ping succeeds? (i.e at least one of the default 4 pings works)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In general, you can use the label/goto syntax in a batch file.

```
:repeat
your-command || goto :repeat
echo Success!
```

The `||` will only run the second command if the first one fails.  Failure in this case means a nonzero exit code, so it will only work with commands that set `%errorlevel%` to 0 for success or nonzero for failure.

For the specific case of `ping.exe`, the exit code is not always nonzero on failure.  In that case, you can use `find.exe` to search the output of `ping` for a success message and set the errorlevel like we need.

```
:repeat
(ping -n 1 www.google.com | find "TTL=") || goto :repeat
echo Success!
```

(Thanks to Stephan for the explanation and solution regarding ping.exe exit codes)

Comment: `%errorlevel%` of `ping` is not reliable ("`reply from <localhost>: destination not reachable`" gives `%errorlevel%`= 0). Therefore better use errorlevel of `... | find "TTL"`

Comment: Understood.  For the specific case when the command is `ping`, your answer is more complete.  My intention was to illustrate the `command || do-on-error` syntax, in order to answer the more general question "How to run command until it succeeds?".  Alternatively, OP could change the question title to "How to run ping.exe until it succeeds."

Comment: @RyanBemrose you are right, for the more general question is better answered by yours.

Answer (score 7):

just loop the command, until it's successful:

```
:Loop
ping -n 1 www.google.com | find "TTL="
if not %errorlevel% equ 0 goto :Loop
echo Connection established
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put your command in a loop as demonstrated below:

```
:Loop
ping -n 1 www.google.com | find "TTL="
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :Loop
echo Connection established
```

Mind the operator neq above. That's the "not equal to" operator in Command Line Scripting.