# Run Grails command from batch file until it succeed

Tags: windows, batch-file, grails

**Description:**

- *Grails* project with several plugin dependencies (many of them can not be resolved instantly due to connectivity issues, some other are being resolved properly very quickly)
- I run *grails* from the *command line* on the project's root in order to get the grails plugins installed successfully in my project but as some of them fails I have to run the same command again (and sometimes again)

**Question:**

How could I make a **batch file for Windows *(10)*** in order to execute the *grails* command over and over again until its result is successful

**>>>** I tried with this: [How to run command until it succeeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152934/how-to-run-command-until-it-succeeds), but I had not luck with it. It **executes** the command the **first time only** and then stops even when **there were some errors resolving the dependencies** as shown in the image below.

[image]

Some help would be really appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534244/execute-a-command-asynchronously-while-redirecting-the-output-to-a-file-in-a-bat is a good staring point start /b "" myCommand >output.txt >2&1 that should probably cover what you want inside your first loop script --- then really if it has worked it will produce a war file and you can check to see if you have that during each iteration of the loop if you do end it and success

Comment: What code did you try.  Questions should show the code you are attempting to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround:

**Logic:**

- Make sure there is not a war on the destination folder intended for this on your grails project structure.
- Execute the "grails war" command, but not just doing a *grails war* on the batch but **call grails war**. It turns out this was a key aspect here. Since when the command is not preceded by the *call* keyword, grails executes and then stops the batch, it means the following lines are never executed (at least when the grails command fails)
- Check whether the war file  exists or not
- If it fails, then retry
- If successful, then done!

**Code:**

```
@echo off

:loop
    echo Executing command...

    call grails war

    if exist "<full_path_to_war_file>" (
        echo Success!
    ) else (
        echo Failed!
        echo Retrying!
        goto loop
    )

echo Done!
```

**Important:** This variant uses the functionality of grails for creating a war. Grails, before creating the war, tries to resolve those pending dependencies, so if this fails, the war is never made, and this way, the failure of the dependencies resolution can be detected.

I'd like to say I've never had done a .bat before until now (so, this might be improved a lot), and thanks a lot to those who posted here.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for comment. Following modification of [How to run command until it succeeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32152992/3439404) might do the job:

```
:repeat
(grails command here |find /I "Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies") &&goto :repeat
echo Success!
```

Read [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

> - `commandA && commandB`      Run *commandA*, if it succeeds then run *commandB*
> - `commandA || commandB`      Run *commandA*, if it fails then run *commandB*

and [FIND will return an ErrorLevel as follows](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html):

> - `0` String found in at least one of the files.
> - `1` String not found
> - `2` If any files in the list do not exist or if no files match a wildcard mask. An invalid switch is given.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @JosefZ!, however with this variant, the grails comand is executed and even when there are errors the console prints "echo Success!
Success!" and stops there. Check my answer, I found a solution.